# Did Obama mention in his book he was born in Kenya?

Tags: history, barack-obama

[While talking to CNN, Donald Trump](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHaToylOZDs) said President Barack Obama himself wrote that he was born in Kenya. Is it true that the President's book said this?

> When his publisher comes out with a statement from him made in the 1990s that he was born in Kenya and he was raised in Indonesia [...]

- Trump, at [4m03s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHaToylOZDs&feature=youtu.be&t=4m3s)

> And all I know is last week somebody came out with a very strong statement saying that he stated himself that he was born in Kenya and raised in Indonesia. Now I didn't make that statement. That was made by  I assume either the publisher or the President himself. And, that's the statement. That's a pretty hard statement to refute.
>   That was a statement made prior to somebody knowing that he was going to be running for the presidency.

- Trump, at [8m01s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHaToylOZDs&feature=youtu.be&t=8m1s)

[The Daily Trawler came out with an excerpt from a promotional booklet.](http://dailycaller.com/2012/05/17/obama-wasnt-born-in-kenya-except-when-he-claims-he-was-born-in-kenya/)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**No**, it was *never* in his book, rather it was a promotional pamphlet circulated amongst other literary agents, which was not written by President Obama (nor was it approved, or even distributed to him).  [The person (Miriam Goderich) who wrote that particular promotional piece has admitted that it was a mistake](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/OTUS/born-kenya-obamas-literary-agent-misidentified-birthplace-1991/story?id=16372566#.T8gvhcXdMjA).

> "This was nothing more than a fact checking error by me--an agency assistant at the time," Goderich wrote in an emailed statement to Yahoo News. "There was never any information given to us by Obama in any of his correspondence or other communications suggesting in any way that he was born in Kenya and not Hawaii. I hope you can communicate to your readers that this was a simple mistake and nothing more."

The same article states (emphasis mine):

> According to a promotional booklet *produced by* the agency, Acton & Dystel,

And the agent also [states the same to this news agency](http://politicalwire.com/archives/2012/05/17/literary_agent_says_1991_booklet_was_a_mistake.html). And they also state (emphasis mine):

> for circulation *within the publishing industry only*

Even Breitbart ([who doesn't buy into the birther nuttery](http://www.breitbart.com/Big-Government/2012/05/17/The-Vetting-Barack-Obama-Literary-Agent-1991-Born-in-Kenya-Raised-Indonesia-Hawaii)) also states that the pamphlet was produced by the agency, and was not in President Obama's book:

> Breitbart News has obtained a promotional booklet produced in 1991 by Barack Obama's then-literary agency, Acton & Dystel, which touts Obama as "born in Kenya and raised in Indonesia and Hawaii."
>
> The booklet, which was distributed to "business colleagues" in the publishing industry, includes a brief biography of Obama among the biographies of eighty-nine other authors represented by Acton & Dystel.

Note the distinct assertions:  produced by Acton & Dystel; distributed  in the publishing industry;  that this wasn't Obama's book, but rather a listing of 90 authors.

Now, I will give The Trump the benefit of *some* doubt, and he may just be mis-stating what he heard.  However, his history of behaviour and bombastic (thanks Skava for reminding me of that word) style indicates this will become a revisionist position to Mr. Trump.  Now that he has stated it, he will not retract from his position, no matter how wrong he may be.

---

Also related [Is Barack Obama a natural born US citizen?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/is-barack-obama-a-natural-born-us-citizen)

Comment: Understandably, this answer oversteps the question, and hence treads into duplicate territory. (The question is whether Obama's book makes the claim, not whether Donald Trump is generally right about this issue or a bloviating ignoramus.)

Comment: I don't need proof of his birth certificate. I think the question here, is is fair to say, obama mentioned in his book he was born in Kenya. The answer seems to be yes. Not in a book though but in a pamphlet as far as I understand now.

Comment: @Believer no, the answer is NO.  A _publicist_ said it, in a pamphlet.

Comment: @Believer If you can read an answer that states clearly "Obama did NOT write that he was born in Kenya" and conclude that Obama wrote that he was born in Kenya, then you are beyond the help of rational people.

Comment: When Obama approves it, then it is Obama not his publicist. Do not need to get me wrong, I am his supporter. But why should I close my eyes?

Comment: @Believer is anyone claiming that he "approved" the publicist pamphlet?  Again, this was meant to be a pamphlet that was circulated amongst publishers, and I am quite sure that President Obama himself didn't see it, nor did he write it, or even "approve" it.  Agents do all sorts of things to promote their clients, most without even the client's knowledge.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, that's all the question is about :) Need references for that

Comment: @Believer Both news reports state that it was written by an agent for internal use amongst publishers.  Miriam Goderich wrote it.  Acton & Dystel published and circulated it.  What other references do you require?

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, I would actually edit your answer and have proof of what you mentioned in comments. I would remove the image because it's already beeen answered in another question and I am not arguing his birth certificate. To me, Obama was higher authority than his publicist. If they did something, Obama is responsible for it. It is simple.

Comment: @Believer so if anyone ever makes a mistake while representing you, it's your fault?  So Kathy Lee Gifford is somehow spilled the beans on the fact that Martin Short's wife is still alive somehow?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwCEoIrhboE  This was done in 1991 when President Obama was just some young Harvard Grad who was trying to get books published...  Your standard is strange to say the least.  Miriam Goderich's own admission to the mistake isn't proof?

Comment: @Believer NO WAY, it isn't as simple as that. The publicist did not ask for Obama's approval or permission before circulating the pamphlet, he did no personally write or approve the bio, which contained a simple mistake.

Comment: @SamIAm I wouldn't call stating a wrong country of birth a small mistake, especially when the two countries are separated by an ocean

Comment: @ryathal, I said simple mistake, not small mistake. From my experience with the people who typically write these bios the level of fact checking is generally very minimum. Mistakes aren't uncommon. See also [Cowboy Bebop at his computer](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CowboyBebopAtHisComputer).

Comment: @Ryathal for what it's worth, Ms Goderich could have looked for any Obama and turned up a record on the President's father and conflated the two.  Heck, if you look up my name, you could easily think I was an Olympic Swimmer that also starred in Attack of the Killer Tomatoes...  Mistakes are EASY to make, humans do it pretty much all the time.

Comment: +1 for the announcement from the advertiser.  That is the first evidence i have seen that would be impossible to fake.

Comment: @Ryathal, totally agree with you. This was not a *small* mistake. But well crowd here seems to be democratic :)

Comment: @Believer I know you are acknowledging it, but I want to make it crystal clear, SamIAm didn't say small, she said SIMPLE (as in easy to make).  Too many people conflate the two.  When you say `crowd here seems to be democratic` do you mean Democrat?  One describes a form of government, while the other is a political party.  And I'd like to see you back up that assertion.  I for one am _not_ a Democrat or Republican.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella, it is simple mistake but if his publicist can make such a mistake, we can't blame republicans. I meant democrats party here. BTW I edited your answer, removed reference to Birth certificate which was not asked in the question.

Comment: @Believer Consider this historic example of a simple (but not small) publishing mistake. When [Alfred Nobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Nobel)'s brother Ludvig died a French newspaper published a obituary for Alfred thinking it was Alfred who died. Alfred was so upset about the content of his own obituary, which condemned him for his invention of dynamite, that he modified his will to establish and fund the Nobel Prizes upon his death so his legacy would be more positive.

Comment: @Believer I don't see anyone blaming Republicans for the mistake?  Or do you mean we can't blame Republicans for being gullible or willing to accept any wild assertions about President Obama's birth?  Then, yes we can, because they are being credulous.

Comment: That Political Wire link unfortunately now gives me a "page not found."

Comment: Sam I am didn’t Mark Twain cancel a newspaper subscription after they published his obituary?

Answer (score 10):

As linked from the site you provided in the question, the [Political Wire reports](https://web.archive.org/web/20140910030638/http://politicalwire.com/archives/2012/05/17/literary_agent_says_1991_booklet_was_a_mistake.html) that the author of a promotional booklet that included a brief erroneous bio of Obama has explained:

> You're undoubtedly aware of the brouhaha stirred up by Breitbart about the erroneous statement in a client list Acton & Dystel published in 1991 (for circulation within the publishing industry only) that Barack Obama was born in Kenya.  This was nothing more than a fact checking error by me -- an agency assistant at the time.  There was never any information given to us by Obama in any of his correspondence or other communications suggesting in any way that he was born in Kenya and not Hawaii.  I hope you can communicate to your readers that this was a simple mistake and nothing more.

Note: This was a promotional booklet for his then-literary agent, Acton & Dystel. It is not part of [his book of memoirs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreams_from_My_Father).