# Where do the claims about Obama being Keyan born and using a foreign passport come from?

Tags: politics, barack-obama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did Obama mention in his book he was born in Kenya?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/did-obama-mention-in-his-book-he-was-born-in-kenya)

To a friend who believes Obama was born outside the US I sent him links to all the excellent articles on this site. But then I got this reply:

> Why would he claim to be Kenyan born in his campaign for Illinois
>   Senate?
>
> What passport did he travel on when he went to prohibited countries as
>   a student?
>
> 27% of the people believing he is foreign born is a substantial
>   amount, knowing he has spent millions of dollars to avoid going to
>   court over it.
>
> The only birth certificates released were forged as proven by 
>   forensic experts, including the Maricopa County Sheriff.
>
> Doesn't matter what Trump said. Obama has never proved his citizenship.

I know the subject has been exhausted but I'm convinced there are answers to those questions and I can finally put this to rest! And, sure, I've asked for citations about things like saying he was Kenyan born during his campaign but all I get are links to more conspiracy theory sites and fake news stories.

Comment: This covers the "Kenyan-born" state senate business - he never claimed it, a Kenyan newspaper erroneously altered an Associated Press article to say so: http://www.snopes.com/politics/obama/birthers/ap.asp

Comment: Which "prohibited countries?" This claim is vague and I can't find any other reference to it online.

Comment: This was answered in this question http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/did-obama-mention-in-his-book-he-was-born-in-kenya

Comment: How can it possibly be pertinent what 27% of the people believe? 27% of the people are dumb as a post (an estimate, based on the above statements) and are willing to believe whatever their favorite media machine feeds them.

Comment: The only thing even remotely accurate in the claim is the first sentence of the final paragraph. *It doesn't matter what Donald Trump says*. Never has, never will.