# Was Hitler the father of Obama?

Tags: barack-obama, adolf-hitler

In this video they claim that Obama's farther was Adolf Hitler. Is this really true?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XesDygYTmWo

If he went to Kenya why did he not move to Tanzania which was an old German colony with an German impact. Even if the local population liked him did they not recognized him or did they not. I don't think the local population of Kenya had television not even newspapers at that time.

Comment: A video that start with the statement *It has long been assumed that Adolf Hitler committed suicide...* isn't worth any serious consideration. That plus another half dozen red flags....

Comment: The professor talking in the video explicitly says it's "complete nonsense and pure invention to claim that [Hitler] was able to escape to Africa. It is also straight up idiotic to claim that he fathered Barack Obama." Source: watched the video, am a native German speaker.

Comment: Is there no end to conspiracy theories?

Comment: I don't think this claim is notable. Anyone can post a youtube video. And I sincerely doubt many will take this seriously.

Answer (score 4):

No.

- Adolf Hitler died on 30 April 1945.
- Barack Obama was born on 4 August 1961.

Death of Hitler:

> 30 April 2005 marked the sixtieth anniversary of the suicide of Adolf Hitler in his bunker below the Reich Chancellery in Berlin. ...
>
> At the end of the Second World War various members of Hitler's personal staff, who had been with him in the bunker during April 1945, were interrogated by Allied officers seeking to establish beyond possible doubt that Hitler had died.
>
> Their questioning concentrated on the events that took place in the Bunker during the last days of April. ...
>
> By the morning of 30 April Russian forces had reached the nearby Potsdamer Platz and the sounds of battle were all around. One version on record suggests that Eva was overheard crying, "I would rather die here. I do not want to escape". She and Hitler later emerged from their suite, their personal staff having been assembled, and went round the room shaking hands silently. Everyone knew that the time had come.
>
> Junge recalled that she and Christian both asked Hitler for a poison capsule, having noted the rapid effect that the poison had had on Hitler's dog. Hitler gave them one each, saying as he did so that he was sorry he had no better parting gift and that he wished his generals had been as poised and brave as they were. Eva embraced Junge and, in what seems to have been her last recorded words said, "Take my fur coat as a memory. I always like well-dressed women". Then, saying "It is finished, goodbye", Hitler took Eva back into their rooms for the last time. **During the afternoon Hitler shot himself** and Eva took the poison capsule that he had given her.

[Hitler's Last Days, MI5](https://www.mi5.gov.uk/hitlers-last-days)

For a more detailed study of the death of Adolf Hitler, see Hugh Trevor-Roper's book [The Last Days of Hitler](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DTADHUF7al8C&lpg=PP1).

Birth of Obama:

> With a father from Kenya and a mother from Kansas, President Obama was born in Hawaii on August 4, 1961.

[President Barack Obama, The White House](https://www.whitehouse.gov/administration/president-obama)

See also: [Is Barack Obama a natural born US citizen?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/is-barack-obama-a-natural-born-us-citizen/1356) which has further sources including President Obama's birth certificate.

Comment: While your first reference is acceptable, I would argue that official government web site wording isn't exactly a good citation for a fact about a government leader. The content providers are, after all, paid by and hired by, said leader.

Comment: @user5341 I thought that someone might say that, but it seemed sensible to address one claim at a time. We've already covered the 'birther' claims here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/is-barack-obama-a-natural-born-us-citizen/1356 - I'll add a link to that in my answer.